# Google Analytics eCommerce Report Local Currency

Tags: google-analytics, transactions, report

new here and looking for help.

I'm trying to get the amount people are spending on a products for a website in local currency.

I'm looking at a GA page for someone overseas and the currency values from itemRevenue for each productName I'm seeing in my report in Sheets are not looking like they're local to that store but rather my countries currency. I've tried localItemRevenue but that gave an error saying the dimensions and metrics can't be used together. I've got date/hour included as well in the report.

I tried to use itemRevenue with currencyCode to get around this but they couldn't be used together either.

I thought I could use transactionRevenue along with productName/date/hour/minute but that didn't work (I realised because more than one item can be bought per transaction).

Could someone tell me what GoogleAnalytics uses for currency here and if it can be solved easily?

Comment: The report you are seeing is in the GA interface or in Google Sheets? Also the error that you encountered 'these dimensions and metrics can't be used together' is it from an API call or from Query Explorer ?

Comment: This is in Google Sheets so I'm guessing this is from the Query Explorer. Could you offer me any more assistance? Thanks @Igneel64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear to me.

However I am assuming that you want to set local currency of your client's country in Google Analytics account.
You can change your currency:

1) Login to your Google Analytics Account

2) Select the View & Click on View Settings.

3) Set "Currency displayed as" -> currency of your choice.

Unless and until you set your desired currency here, you won't be able to get it in Web Interface, Query Explorer, Sheets or API.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Saffire Tech! You were spot on. Thanks for that. I've tried to change it but the client blocked our access to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics uses the currency settings that are set in the data view settings.

If you send a different currency, as specified by the currency field in the e-commerce-tracking, GA will convert it to the currency set in the view settings as long as it is on the [list of supported currencies](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205902?hl=en).

So the first thing to do would be to check the view settings - this defaults to USD, and it happens amazingly often that people fail to set the proper currency.

Next thing to check would be to see what is actually sent to the property - if there is a mismatch between view currency and currency set in the code the values will be converted from the latter to the former.